# aws architecture icons のライセンスは？

Tags: aws, ライセンス

AWS には、オフィシャルのアイコン集がある様子です。 https://aws.amazon.com/jp/architecture/icons/

> お客様やパートナーがアーキテクチャーダイアグラムを作成するために以下のリソースをお使いいただけます。

とありますが、逆にそれ以上の利用規約っぽいものを見つけられずにいます。

#### 質問

- aws architecture icons のライセンスは、どうなっていますか？

Comment: こちらでも利用規約は見つかりませんでした。代わりに[PowerPoint 用ツールキットのダウンロード]でダウンロードしたPowerPointのファイルを確認すると、アイコン利用のガイドラインなら記載されていました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2020 年 7 月現在、 https://aws.amazon.com/jp/architecture/icons/ には以下のように書かれています。通常使う分にはこの表記で充分ではないでしょうか。

> AWS は、お客様やパートナーがアーキテクチャダイアグラムを作成するために以下のリソースを使用することを許可します。

どこかに公開したり書籍等で用いたりするのが不安であれば、AWS のサポートに聞いてみるのが良さそうです。